# how to combine two QuerySet obtain from loop in django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

**i have two QuerySet obtain from loop in django i want to combine in one QuerySet

this is the code**

```
for m in [1,2]:
        gpu=Gpu.objects.filter(brand=m)
        print(gpu)
```

and the result is

```
<QuerySet [<Gpu: GIGABYTE AORUS GeForce RTX 3070 8GB>]> 

<QuerySet [<Gpu: MSI Gaming GeForce RTX 3070 8GB>, <Gpu: MSI Suprim GeForce RTX 3080 10GB>, <Gpu: MSI Non-locking Gaming GeForce RTX 3060>]>
```

**but i need to combine to be in one QuerySet like this**

`<QuerySet [<Gpu: GIGABYTE AORUS GeForce RTX 3070 8GB>,<Gpu: MSI Gaming GeForce RTX 3070 8GB>, <Gpu: MSI Suprim GeForce RTX 3080 10GB>, <Gpu: MSI Non-locking Gaming GeForce RTX 3060>]>`

Comment: You can use [`__in`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in) so `Gpu.objects.filter(brand__in=m)`

Comment: thanks but i got this error :                                                                                                                                                                                                        Type Error at /shop/gpu'int' object is not iterable

Comment: Ah my bad it should be `Gpu.objects.filter(brand__in=[1, 2])`

Comment: thanks this is good solution

Answer (score 0):

```py
filter = None
for m in [1,2]:
    q = Q(brand=m)
    filter = filter | q

gpu=Gpu.objects.filter(filter)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
gpus = Gpu.objects.filter(brand__in=[1, 2])
```